# extend Python namedtuple with many @properties?

Tags: python, properties, namedtuple

How can namedtuples be extended or subclassed with many additional @properties ?
For a few, one can just write the text below; but there are many,
so I'm looking for a generator or property factory.
One way would be to generate text from `_fields` and exec it;
another would be an add_fields with the same effect at runtime.
(My @props are to get rows and fields
in a database scattered across several tables,
so that `rec.pname` is `persontable[rec.personid].pname`;
but namedtuples-with-smart-fields would have other uses too.)

```
""" extend namedtuple with many @properties ? """
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple( "Person", "pname paddr" )  # ...
persontable = [
    Person( "Smith", "NY" ),
    Person( "Jones", "IL" )
    ]

class Top( namedtuple( "Top_", "topid amount personid" )):
    """ @property 
        .person -> persontable[personid]
        .pname -> person.pname ...
    """
    __slots__ = ()
    @property
    def person(self):
        return persontable[self.personid]

    # def add_fields( self, Top.person, Person._fields ) with the same effect as these ?
    @property
    def pname(self):
        return self.person.pname
    @property
    def paddr(self):
        return self.person.paddr
    # ... many more

rec = Top( 0, 42, 1 )
print rec.person, rec.pname, rec.paddr
```

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question there?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe you want the properties to show up in the tuple? Overwrite getitem if you want that.

Comment: I'm confused too.  You seem to be doing exactly what you should be to get the effect you're asking about.  What problem are you having?

Comment: sorry, wasn't clear: looking for a generator or property factory
for half-a-dozen tables, some with 20 fields

Comment: now that you've updated the question, that's an interesting problem, and I'll think on it a bit.

Answer (score 19):

The answer to your question

> How can namedtuples be extended or
>   subclassed with additional `@properties`
>   ?

is: exactly the way you're doing it!  What error are you getting?  To see a simpler case,

```
>>> class x(collections.namedtuple('y', 'a b c')):
...   @property
...   def d(self): return 23
... 
>>> a=x(1, 2, 3)
>>> a.d
23
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
class Top( namedtuple( "Top_", "topid amount personid" )): 
    """ @property  
        .person -> persontable[personid] 
        .pname -> person.pname ... 
    """ 
    __slots__ = () 
    @property 
    def person(self): 
        return persontable[self.personid] 

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        if attr in Person._fields:
            return getattr(self.person, attr)
        raise AttributeError("no such attribute '%s'" % attr)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's one approach, a little language: 
turn this into Python text like the above, and exec it.
(Expanding text-to-text is easy to do, and easy to test —
you can look at the intermediate text.)
I'm sure there are similar if not-so-little such, links please ?

```
# example of a little language for describing multi-table databases 3feb
# why ?
# less clutter, toprec.pname -> persontable[toprec.personid].pname
# describe in one place: easier to understand, easier to change

Top:
    topid amount personid
    person: persontable[self.personid] + Person
        # toprec.person = persontable[self.personid]
        # pname = person.pname
        # locid = person.locid
        # todo: chaining, toprec.city -> toprec.person.loc.city

Person:
    personid pname locid
    loc: loctable[self.locid] + Loc

Loc:
    locid zipcode province city
```